# How can I get error details from an if condition activity in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am creating a pipeline in which I have to pass a variable in a stored procedure from an **If Condition** in ADF.

The flow of the pipeline is like this:-

Lookup --> If Condition --> Stored Procedure

What I am trying to achieve is, I want to get the execution details (Only Failed or Succeed) of the **If Condition**.
How can I do that?

**THANKS!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out only about the error details:-

You can simply use the function in ADF like this:-

```
@activity('if Condition1').error.message
```

By the way the upper answer given by @AbhishekKhandave-MT is also good, but you can simply use the `.error` JSON to get the error code and message.

Thanks for helping out @AbhishekKhandave-MT

Answer (score 2):

There are two approach as given below.

You can get success or fail message using Set Variable activity.

[image]

[image]

Other Approach you can follow is, Send an email notification for an error. For this approach you can follow this [article](https://kohera.be/azure-cloud/custom-email-notification-in-azure-data-factory/) by WOUT CARDOEN

Refer -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/85468/adf-need-status-of-actual-activity-failure-in-the.html